# Sql Query giving wrong answer

Tags: mysql

I keep getting the wrong answer when I run my query. I have tried it with `LEFT`, `INNER` and `FULL`, changed `=` to `LIKE` and changed `yes` to `no` but keep getting the same incorrect answer.

```
SELECT Is_Class_Rep,Course_Name
From Students
Left JOIN Course
ON Course.Course_ID=Students.Course_ID
Where Is_Class_Rep LIKE '%No%';

INSERT INTO Students
(Student_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Date_Of_Birth,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Year_In_College,Is_Class_Rep,Date_Of_Training,Role_SU,Staff_ID)
Values
(3,'Hillay','Clinton','1984-04-06',0869456633,'hilldog@whitehouse.com','2nd Year', 'No','','',''),
(4,'Bill','Clinton','1983-06-06',0853215896,'oraloffice@whitehouse.com','3rd Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','Clubs & Societies','2'),
(5,'Donald','Trump','1987-05-12',086321321,'combeover@whitehouse.com','1st Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','',''),
(6,'Stan','Smith','1990-04-20',0875846842,'ss@fbi.com','2nd Year', 'No','','',''),
(7,'Stan','Marsh','1989-01-26',086845665,'wendy@southpark.com','1st Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','',''),
(8,'Bruce','Wayne','1991-04-10',0878989856,'iamthebatman@gotham.com','3rd Year', 'No','','',''),
(9,'Fred','Claus','1992-02-17',084258258,'onceayear@northpole.com','3rd Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','Entertainment','3'),
(10,'Zack','Smith','1988-10-18',086799878,'wheresmirig@gogle.com','1st Year', 'No','','',''),
(11,'Hugo','Cruz','1984-05-05',0851597532,'hugo@yahoo.com','2nd Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','Equality','4');
```

I noticed I was missing a Course_ID so I did add it in

```
INSERT Course
(Course_ID,Course_Name,Full_Part_Time,Course_Fees,Course_Leader)
Values
(1,'Radio Production','Full Time','Yes','Rick Rubin'),
(2, 'Marketing','Part Time','NO','Gavin Evans'),
(3,'Business Information Systemys','Full Time','Yes','Liam Malone'),
(4,'Mixology','Full Time','No','Slim Denby'),
(5,'Business Studies','Part Time','Yes','John Doe');
```

I have 2 table Students and Courses and I have populated both. In Students I have a column called Is_Class_Rep and I have entered Constraints only allowing Yes or No to be entered and I have made sure that one of the course has no class rep. The Foreign key is a course id. On my Second table I have my course and I am try to create a query that will give a list of the course with no class rep but every time I run the query it just lists all the courses with either yes opposite all the course or no opposite the course.

Comment: can you attach tables and some rows?

Comment: Some sample of data would help us

Comment: INSERT Course
(Course_ID,Course_Name,Full_Part_Time,Course_Fees,Course_Leader)
Values
(1,'Radio Production','Full Time','Yes','Rick Rubin'),
(2, 'Marketing','Part Time','NO','Gavin Evans'),
(3,'Business Information Systemys','Full Time','Yes','Liam Malone'),
(4,'Mixology','Full Time','No','Slim Denby'),
(5,'Business Studies','Part Time','Yes','John Doe');

Comment: NSERT INTO Students
(Student_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Date_Of_Birth,Phone_Number,Email_Address,Year_In_College,Is_Class_Rep,Date_Of_Training,Role_SU,Staff_ID)
Values
(3,'Hillay','Clinton','1984-04-06',0869456633,'hilldog@whitehouse.com','2nd Year', 'No','','',''),
(4,'Bill','Clinton','1983-06-06',0853215896,'oraloffice@whitehouse.com','3rd Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','Clubs & Societies','2'),
(5,'Donald','Trump','1987-05-12',086321321,'combeover@whitehouse.com','1st Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','',''),

Comment: (6,'Stan','Smith','1990-04-20',0875846842,'ss@fbi.com','2nd Year', 'No','','',''),
(7,'Stan','Marsh','1989-01-26',086845665,'wendy@southpark.com','1st Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','',''),(8,'Bruce','Wayne','1991-04-10',0878989856,'iamthebatman@gotham.com','3rd Year', 'No','','',''),(9,'Fred','Claus','1992-02-17',084258258,'onceayear@northpole.com','3rd Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','Entertainment','3'),
(10,'Zack','Smith','1988-10-18',086799878,'wheresmirig@gogle.com','1st Year', 'No','','',''),
(11,'Hugo','Cruz','1984-05-05',0851597532,'hugo@yahoo.com','2nd Year', 'Yes','2015-10-21','Equality','4');

Comment: don't exist relation between two tables.. Course.Course_ID = Students.Course_id never match..

Comment: Please edit your question and add this data there

Comment: Students.Course_ID not exist! check your DB.. use intermediate table where exist Student_ID and Course_ID.

Comment: Good grief. There IS an edit button.

Comment: Sorry I manual input the Course_ID yesterday still getting the same problem after I assigned values to them

Comment: You still haven't included a Course_ID on your Student table - you have only included one on your Course table. Without either a Course_ID on the Student table, or a link table to join the two (as suggested by Cuchu), you cannot link one table to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing query is returning a list of courses that have at least one Student that is not a class rep (listed once for each student that is not a class rep, for good measure.)

Your query should instead select a list of all courses that have no student who is a class rep - one way of doing this is using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT Course_Name
From Course as C
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 
 FROM Students as S
 WHERE C.Course_ID=S.Course_ID AND S.Is_Class_Rep = 'Yes');
```

Comment: S.Course_ID not exist.. see fourth comment in OP.

Comment: @Cuchu: That's a problem with the table structure defined in the comments on the question. If the original query in the question did not produce an error when running, then there should be a Course_ID field on  Students.